# Add label to an intent of a composite entity in LUIS via LUIS API using c#

Tags: c#, bots, azure-language-understanding

I figured out how to add label to an intent, but not sure how can I do it for the composite entities. Here is the code which is working fine for non-composite entities;

```
public static void AddLabels(string originalMessage, string intent, List<Label> labels)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(string.Empty);

            var uri = "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v1.0/prog/apps/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/example?" + queryString;

            // Request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            HttpResponseMessage response;
            string body = string.Empty;
            string entityLabels = string.Empty;

            //get the position of the labels
            foreach (var label in labels)
            {
                entityLabels += label.ToString() + ",";
            }
            //remove last ","
            entityLabels = entityLabels.Remove(entityLabels.Length - 1, 1);

            body = string.Format("{{\"ExampleText\": \"{0}\", \"SelectedIntentName\": \"{1}\", \"EntityLabels\": [", originalMessage, intent);
            body += entityLabels + "]}";
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);


            using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
            {
                content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
                try
                {
                    response = client.PostAsync(uri, content).Result;
                }catch(Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }

        }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, we basically need to add one more label in the list of labels with the composite entity name and pass that list of labels to the above method and it will automatically resolves the relationship for you.

for example; 
if contact is the composite entity and contact.firstname and contact.lastname are the child entities.

so in the below example scenario;
Original message : I want to create Sam Smith as a new contact.
word to be marked with the label: Sam
intent for the label : contact.firstname
word to be marked with the label: Smith
intent for the label : contact.lastname
Now, for the parent which is contact, we will use the statement which needs to be marked : create Sam Smith as a new contact
label for the intent :  contact
This will wrap both firstname and lastname within an contact composite entity.